# How to get click and change debug text to dev top right corner red debug banner?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying to change the name of that banner "**debug**" to "**dev**", "**stage**", "**prod**". programmatically

[image]

I want to do some action on the click of that debug banner.

I want to override all functionality of that debug banner.

Do I just have to create a new custom banner using this:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html

Or is there any approach.

Does that debug banner is just showing it in debug mode only? Is it possible to make to use multiple purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
               const Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 55, right: 50),
            child: const Banner(
              message: "Custom",
              location: BannerLocation.bottomStart,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order for you to do this you not only have to create your own Banner but you also need to create your own WidgetsApp. Not like a MaterialApp that wraps options around a WidgetsApp, but your own WidgetsApp. Which means you'll have to copy flutter's code for WidgetsApp and modify from there.

Comment: Another suggestion might be to make a fork of the flutter repo, make your modifications to your fork that would allow for a more dynamic debug Banner and submit a PR as this might not be a bad idea for a feature in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved by wrapping your app in a [Banner](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html) widget at whatever level of the widget tree suits you.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Banner(
    message: 'message...',
    location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
    child: Scaffold(...),
  );
}
```